# Should partial answer 16426 be deleted?

Tags: discussion

Should the [partial answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/16426) to [How many different endings does the Sholay?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/16425/7083) be deleted?

I was going to add it to the question but then I thought it could be an answer so I put it as one. But aren't partial answers *answers*, although not complete?

To me this definitely isn't "not an answer".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it fits more into the question as part of the *"what have you tried"*. While giving some valuable information it doesn't really answer the question. You're not going to accept it as it isn't in any way a complete answer. It only encourages a list of answers with each answer adding a single ending and saying *"but I think there might be another one"*, which wouldn't be a good situation (while nothing prevents this from happening anyway, your self-answer really encourages that).

You are asking how many endings there are and a proper answer would list all those in a single answer. Your answer is only a hint to a complete answer and therefore fits more into the question.